How big was my latest Time Machine backup?
I can't find anything that tells me how big the latest Time Machine backup was. For most folders, you can choose "Get Info" and it tells you the size of the folder. But when I do that for the latest Time Machine backup, it doesn't give me that information.
Why not? Where can I find that info?
I'm running Monteray on Macbook Air (Early 2015).

What does Disk Utility show for snapshots on the affected destination disk? I’ll see if I can link to some tools, on APFS the file deduplication is handled differently than older OS so your question illustrates a very important concept that Get Info can’t be trusted for anything except how much space it might take to copy  the files to a brand new disk.

I attempted an answer, but realised (from a comment to @bmike) that your TM disk is HFS+ and not APFS format. Perhaps make that clear in the question.

To Gilby: until bmike mentioned APFS, I had never heard of it. But I read up on it and USB drives do not use APFS, so there's nothing really to make clear in the question.

I have a USB disk for TM, formatted as APFS. I'd agree that it's more difficult to get accurate diff from APFS, because it's more flexible.

I use an app called BackupLoupe from soma-zone. It shows the sizes of all TM backups, and allows you to browse them easily to see the incremental changes.
Ordinary Finder or Terminal operations give misleading results because TM makes use of hard links to share unchanged files and directories between successive backups. So the unchanged portions would appear to take up space in all the backups, but there's actually just one copy.

The best tool for this is a free tool.

https://eclecticlight.co/consolation-t2m2-and-log-utilities/

It knows a lot about reading the logs and the backup to determine how long a backup took, how much data was transferred, and why an incremental backup doesn’t take up all the space that you see in finder if you ask it for a folder size measurement.

I tried 'sudo du -sh 2024-05-16/* from /Volumes/My Passport for Mac/Backups.backupdb/Macbook Air. It told me 33GB. Is that the whole backup and not just the diffs? Do I need the utility you mention to get the diffs--how much space a new backup actually takes?
